# Run Tomcat with domain name and without port number on Windows running IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis

I have a Windows 2008 server and few websites serving from IIS 7.0. Each of the website are configured to use a different domain names. I have another JSP application on the same server running Apache Tomcat 6.. I can configured the JSP application to use a different domain name and it runs fine on port 8080. The problem is - I need to configure JSP application to run using just the domain name without the port number.

When I configure for port 80, the application does not run and 404 error is shown. On the console, it states port 80 is taken by another application. How can I configure JSP application to run on port 80?

Since I already have a custom domain name, I don't think the port should be an important factor for running the website.

Comment: If you want to quick and dirty way, first of all check which application use port 80, You can use this SO answer to check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows/23718720#23718720. Other way you need to setUp Apache or NGINX server and redirect the request to specific domain names which is clean but need learning to Apache or NGINX port domain name redirections.

Comment: IIS default web site might be grabbing the request. Did you disable IIS to see if it works with it off?

Comment: I haven't disabled IIS to see if it works but then I can't disable IIS as there are sites running from it.